# multiple instances of "the value of the local variable is not used"

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jbutton, chess

I'm learning Java and trying to make a chess game. The first thing I want to do is set up a frame as a board and then use an 8x8 grid of JButtons to make the squares on the board, however it appears that some of my code isn't being used at all.

My frame will load, but none of the buttons are added, the array I'm using to store the location of each square isn't being used and apparently neither is the grid that I want to add the buttons to. I've tinkered with almost every part of the code but can't figure it out.

I've added where Eclipse gives the warnings in quotes
    //"like this"

Here is my ChessBoard class:

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon; //"the import is never used"
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JButton; //"the import is never used"
import Logic.ChessSquare;



public class ChessBoard {

    //chess board constructor
    public ChessBoard() throws IOException {

        //create grid and grid dimensions
        GridLayout grid = new GridLayout(8,8); //"the value of the local variable grid is never used"

        //create frame and set specifications of frame
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setTitle("I should have started this sooner");
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        //initialise 3D array
        int[][] square; //"the value of the local variable square is never used"

        //create 64 instances of ChessSquare and assign each square as an element in the 3D array
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
            for(int l = 0; l < 8; l++){
                ChessSquare chessSquare = new ChessSquare(i, l);
                square = new int[i][l];
                frame.add(chessSquare);
            }
        }



    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        new ChessBoard();
    }

}
```

and here is my ChessSquare class:

```
package Logic;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;

//chess square class, 1 instance of which for each square in the grid
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ChessSquare extends JButton {


    //instance variables for position and piece
    public int posX;
    public int posY;
    public String selectedPiece;

    //constructor for chess squares, loads image and adds to new JButton
    public ChessSquare(int x, int y) throws IOException {
                BufferedImage buttonIcon = ImageIO.read(new File("E:\\Eclipse\\ChessF\\src\\Images\\EmptySquare.jpg"));
                JButton button = new JButton(new ImageIcon(buttonIcon)); //"the value of the local variable button is never used"
                setVisible(true);
                }

    //accessor method for position
    public void squarePos(int x, int y){
        this.posX = x;
        this.posY = y;
    }

}
```

Thank you in advance.

P.S. When I changed frame.add(chessSquare); to frame.add(ChessSquare); (shown below) the warnings disappear, but then I get the error "ChessSquare cannot be resolved to a variable"

```
//create 64 instances of ChessSquare and assign each square as an element in the 3D array
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
    for(int l = 0; l < 8; l++){
        ChessSquare chessSquare = new ChessSquare(i, l);
        square = new int[i][l];
        frame.add(ChessSquare);
    }
}
```

Ryan, here is the updated code, I left the old above for comparison:

ChessSquare:

```
package Logic;

import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;

//chess square class, 1 instance of which for each square in the grid
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ChessSquare extends JButton {


    //instance variables for position and piece
    public int posX;
    public int posY;
    public String selectedPiece;

    //constructor for chess squares, loads image and adds to new JButton
    public ChessSquare(int x, int y) throws IOException {
                BufferedImage buttonIcon = ImageIO.read(new File("E:\\Eclipse\\ChessF\\src\\Images\\EmptySquare.jpg"));
                this.setIcon((Icon) buttonIcon);
                setVisible(false);
                }

    //accessor method for position
    public void squarePos(int x, int y){
        this.posX = x;
        this.posY = y;
    }

}
```

ChessBoard:

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import Logic.ChessSquare;



public class ChessBoard {

    //chess board constructor
    public ChessBoard() throws IOException {

        //create grid and grid dimensions
        GridLayout grid = new GridLayout(8,8);

        //create frame and set specifications of frame
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setLayout(grid);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setTitle("I should have started this sooner");
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);


        //create 64 instances of ChessSquare and assign each square as an element in the 3D array
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
            for(int l = 0; l < 8; l++){
                ChessSquare chessSquare = new ChessSquare(i, l);
                int[][] square = new int[i][l];
                frame.add(chessSquare);
            }
        }



    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        new ChessBoard();
    }

}
```

Comment: See my comment back to you below, I linked a swing tutorial site that I hope helps you out in your endeavors :). I often use example code as my base when starting out a language or new concept and tailor it from there, because then I start with something I know that works.

Answer (score 2):

Okay from the top, your "import is never used", means that in that file, you do not use those imports, so they are safe to delete, unless you intend to use them in that file, this normally happens when you use eclipse to import the item, but then later decide not to use it. (i.e. delete it)

second, as said before my edit, your gridlayout is not added to your jframe

third, your square says "the value is never used" but this is a mistake by eclipse, you are in fact actually using it, it is only saying that because it is initialized inside of the for loop.

in your last box, it is correct to add `chesssquare` and not the class name `ChessSquare`

Thats probably the best I can do at the moment. Have fun!

Edit:

Also your `JButton button` suffers from the same problem, you are not using it anywhere else :)

Comment: Thank you for clarifying those things :) although I still don't understand why when I run the frame will appear, but none of the buttons, so I just have a blank frame.

Comment: ok, so this is because you are setting the jframe to visible. You need to add the gridlayout to it :). so: do frame.add(gridlayout);, but you need to also add the items to your gridlayout first. I hope this helps, i know programming can be difficult to get the hang of sometimes, but once you get it, its a blast!

Comment: Ha, i see what you mean, lol, Josh, he's correct, its not being used, but eclipse can make that mistake. One thing to note though, the "not used" piece is a hint, not in fact an error

Comment: Cheers guys, added in the gridlayout :) just not got a clue how to get the buttons to appear. I had JButtons appearing no problem when I simply added in JButtons in a more simple version of what I'm trying to do, but now that I'm using ChessSquare as my button I think something's changed and I really have no idea aha.

Comment: Edit your post to reflect the new code, and I can see how to help out

Comment: Try moving your pack() and setVisible(true) call until the end (after your loop), you should look at this example: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/HowtoUseGridLayout.htm

Comment: I think I was approaching this wrong, in the console it's saying the buffered image cannot be cast to javax.swing.icon and it's occuring at 3 points in the program. Strange.

Comment: Eh, because you still need to construct an `ImageIcon` object when calling `setIcon`, simply trying to cast from `BufferedImage` to `Icon` won't work.

Comment: Tim, you're lucky I'm not near you or else I would kiss you! Thank you both, very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Been awhile since I wrote Swing, but I'll give this a shot...

```
GridLayout grid = new GridLayout(8,8); //"the value of the local variable grid is never used"
```

Constructing the `GridLayout` is not enough, you must also use it. E.G. `frame.setLayout(grid);`

```
int[][] square; //"the value of the local variable square is never used"
```

It really isn't it. You should probably delete this line and the erroneous line that initializes it 64 times.

```
JButton button = new JButton(new ImageIcon(buttonIcon)); //"the value of the local variable button is never used"
```

`ChessSquare` is a `JButton`. You need not create another one here. Instead, you should call something like `this.setIcon(new ImageIcon(buttonIcon));`

Again, my Swing is a little rusty, but I'm guessing those answers are close.

Comment: Thanks for helping me get rid of the excess. I think I see what's happened, however I've tried both of the solutions you and Ryan have offered but still my frame is empty when it loads. I think I'm not understanding something pretty fundamental here.